# Yii: Same route but only GET works after confirming there's no controller filter

Tags: yii

My urlManager rules: (basically the one comes default)

```
'<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',`
```

My controller:

```
class SiteController extends Controller {
    public function actionSubscribe() {
        echo 'gdg';
        die();
    }
}
```

My view:

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $this->createUrl('site/subscribe'); ?>" style="display: inline;">
    <input style="margin: 0 18px 0 6px;" type="text" value="e-mail"/>
</form>
```

When I access it using the url `http://localhost/site/subscribe` directly it works, but when I type something in the text field and push my enter button to post the form it says `The system is unable to find the requested action "error".`
I'm very certain that it has something to do with my form. I have so far no problem using active form but for this form I don't have a model and I don't want to use form builder. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"When I access it using the url http://***/site/subscribe directly it works"

=> You execute `subscribe` action with GET method.

"but when I type something in the text field and push my enter button to post the form it says The system is unable to find the requested action "error"."

=> You execute `subscribe` action with POST method.

=> There are some errors and I think Yii try to handle error with your default configure:

```
return array(
    ......
    'components'=>array(
        'errorHandler'=>array(
            'errorAction'=>'site/error',
        ),
    ),
);
```

However, Yii can't find `error` action with your `SiteController` so it throws `The system is unable to find the requested action "error".` You can add `error` action to see information about errors like:

```
public function actionError()
{
    if($error=Yii::app()->errorHandler->error){
        $this->render('error', $error);
     }
}
```

**More info:** The above `error` variable is an array with the following fields:

```
code: the HTTP status code (e.g. 403, 500);
type: the error type (e.g. CHttpException, PHP Error);
message: the error message;
file: the name of the PHP script file where the error occurs;
line: the line number of the code where the error occurs;
trace: the call stack of the error;
source: the context source code where the error occurs.
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The error message said that `The CSRF token could not be verified.`.